# hiding duplicates in a SharePoint view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list-view, xslt-list-view-web-part, duplicate

I have a list with the following information:

[image: All documents view]

I have attempted to create a table of contents by grouping results in the following manner:
[image: TOC view]

However, as you can see, I have duplicated results in this view as there are documents that have the same Manual entries.

So what I want is the ability to display this same library in a table of contents like view where there are no duplicates.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could best go about this? I have tried editing the CAML, but there is still no UNIQUE keyword in SP2010 or SP2013. I tried editing the XSLT for the view but had no luck.

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Danielle

Answer (score 1):

It's not an easy/sexy answer, but you could use Javascript/JQuery to iterate through the returned list items and just hide the duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: these are NOT duplicate results. Every record is showing just once. It may seem like a duplicate entry since you don't group on the "Manual" field, but instead show every list item's "Manual" column value.

This is not a bug. It is how SharePoint works. If you want the "manual" value showing only once, create a nested grouping under the department.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement grouping as showing in the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331530/sharepoint-2013-lists-remove-duplicates-from-list-view